# Count a the number of digits in a cell with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I get a spreadsheet but sometimes they dont give me all the digits I need when running my macro.  So i am trying to find a way to count how many digits are in a cell and then use msgbox to tell me to add a digit to the cell.

```
If Len(A2) <> 7 Then
MsgBox ("Add # to the end ")
Exit Sub
End If
```

I was also wondering if there is a way to use an input box to add the number to the end of the value in excel.  Like if the numbers are 123456 i can put 7 into the input box and it changes the cell value to 1234567

Comment: why `Len(A2)` doesn't suit?

Comment: @simoco I think it's because he is in VBA, and it should be `Len([A2])` or `Len(Range("A2"))`

Comment: yea, is it digits or characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for Characters, But if other Characters are in the cell besides just numbers it counts everything:

```
If Len([A2]) <> 7 Then
    [A2] = [A2].Value & InputBox("Add # to the end ")
End If
```

Comment: Right on the money bro!  I couldnt find anywhere that showed I needed [] around a cell and I actually have never used it before I would never have come up with this

Comment: @user3271518 You can learn about what the `[]` are doing [At This MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223886%28v=office.11%29.aspx)